# ruby on rails server is not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i m new to ruby on rails can any one help me. i cant start my rails server below is the error which m getting

i also tried by installing bundle but getting same error

ahaad@Labbaik:~/Desktop/Ruby_Pro/App_demo$ rails server

Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: Have you tried `gem install jquery-rails`?  Sometimes that'll work when `bundle` doesn't (at least for me, on Linux).

Comment: can you post your gemfile please

Answer (score 0):

Install this gem separately:

```
gem install jquery-rails
```

and run the bundle:

```
bundle install
```

(or)

Look up your Gemfile, add `gem 'jquery-rails'` if Gemfile not contain it, then at your terminial, run

```
bundle install
```